# distributing divs for not overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to generate a "A4" html as a template previous for saving as PDF, my page has 5 divs that cover 100% of the area to print.

I am using position absolute for every div, but somehow they are overlapping a little bit, why that is happening??

```css
 body {
          background: rgb(204,204,204); 
        }
        page[size="A4"] {
          background: white;
          width: 210mm;
          height: 297mm;
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
          margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
          box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        }
        @media print {
          body, page[size="A4"] {
            margin: 0;
            box-shadow: 0;
          }
        }   
        .area100{
          border:1px solid black;
          position:absolute;
          width:210mm;
        }
        .area50{
          font-size:9px;
          padding:10px;
          text-align: justify;
          border:1px solid black;
          position:absolute;
          width:105mm;
          height:98mm;
          overflow:hidden;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  
</head>
<body>
    <page size="A4">
        <div id="header" class="area100" style="height:20mm;">
        This is header
        </div>
        <div id="main" class="area100" style="height:129mm; top: 20mm;">
        This is main
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-left" class="area50" style="top: 149mm">
        {agreement}
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-right" class="area50" style="left:105mm; top: 149mm">
        right
        </div>
        <div id="footer" class="area100" style="top: 247mm; height:50mm">
        This is footer
        </div>
    </page>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always set `top` and `left` attributes for `position: absolute;` because browser will try to guess it and sometimes it's not what you want.

Also element actual width consists of `width + padding`, so when you set `width: 105mm; padding: 10px;` than your actual width is `105mm + 20px`

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
page[size="A4"] {
  background: white;
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
@media print {
  body,
  page[size="A4"] {
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
  }
}
.area100 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 210mm;
}
.area50 {
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  width: 99mm;
  height: 98mm;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<page size="A4">
  <div id="header" class="area100" style="height:20mm;">
    This is header
  </div>
  <div id="main" class="area100" style="height:129mm; top: 20mm;">
    This is main
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-left" class="area50" style="top: 149mm">
    {agreement}
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-right" class="area50" style="left:105mm; top: 149mm">
    right
  </div>
  <div id="footer" class="area100" style="top: 247mm; height:50mm">
    This is footer
  </div>
</page>
```

Comment: Like Justinas said; if you have a look at your margin-top value you'll find that the first box is in fact adjusted 8px from the top due that the body tag comes with margin 8px. This places the bottom of the header div 20mm + 8px from the top, and so on.